# Android startActivity don't call the target activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm having a problem using the startActivity to change from a activity to another.
When I click in a button it should call another activity, and it does this, but it's not the activity that I wanted

My code:

This is the click action of a button, after do startActivity, it opens a white screen.

```
public void initiateRoute(View view) {
    // I have a breakpoint on the line below and it comes here
    Intent i= new Intent(this,GMapsActivity.class); 
    startActivity(i);
}
```

This is my target activity xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_above="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/abc_action_bar_title_item" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pausar Rota"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Parar captura de Rota"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And this is my Activity class:

```
    public class GMapsActivity extends Activity {

        private GoogleMap mMap;

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, PersistableBundle persistentState) {
            // I have another breakpoint on the line below and it never comes here
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState); 
            setContentView(R.layout.map_activity);
            createMap();
        }

        private void createMap() {
            mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
            mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
            final LatLng CIU = new LatLng(35.21843892856462, 33.41662287712097);
            Marker ciu = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(CIU).title("My Office"));
        }
    }
```

I did a lot of searches in stackoverflow, and in the google, and I didn't find nothing that can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you should be crashing. You will need to fix the bugs in `GMapsActivity`. Of note, your layout uses `com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`, but your Java code uses `MapFragment`, and they are not the same thing. You need to decide whether you are going to use native fragments (e.g., `Activity` and `MapFragment`) or if you are going to use the fragment backport (e.g., `FragmentActivity` and `SupportMapFragment`), then implement that in all places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are treating the fragment as if it was an activity. You need to define the fragment and COMMIT the changes in order to see the results, something like this:

```
 mMapFragment = MapFragment.newInstance();
 FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
         getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.my_container, mMapFragment);
 fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

This guide will get you going: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map

Comment: Thanks, worked :) and the problem of don't enter in the onCreate is because, when i created the class, I extended the FragmentActivity class, and overrode the method onCreate of this class, when I changed the "extends" to Activity instead of FragmentActivity, I forgot to override the method onCreate of it, so this is the reason my startActivity didn't go to the method.

When I overrode, the method worked, and your answer for the map fragment did everything works
Thanks.